# mysql count is not working on local server

Tags: mysql, count

i have a wired problem, i have this Mysql Query:

```
 SELECT app.id AS appid,
     (SELECT count(id) FROM data_names WHERE STATUS=1 AND sid = names.sid) AS count
    FROM `data_names` names, data_applications app
    WHERE app.id = names.appid
    AND season = '12'
    HAVING count =5
```

the query works fine on my remote server and works fine on my desktop computer, but on my laptop localhost server  it takes unlimited time to run and never show results.

i installed different versions of mysql server but the same issue. I formatted my laptop and installed new system and same issue there. I tried many optimizations to mysql my.ini but all helpless.

i think there is a daemon messing with my laptop local server.

any suggestions?

Comment: Please provide us with your table structure and settings. Too many missing details.

Comment: Maybe you are missing indexes on your local server

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    app.id AS appid,
    count(dn2.id) AS cnt
FROM 
    `data_names` names
        INNER JOIN data_applications app ON app.id = names.appid AND season = '12'
        INNER JOIN `data_names` dn2 ON dn2.sid = names.sid AND dn2.STATUS=1
GROUP BY appid
HAVING cnt=5
```

I think you will have to review the aliases since some were missing in your version, but this is the idea.

Regards

Comment: If you want my opinion, I would also say that the logic of the query seems crooked. Maybe it is doing something you don't really want. But of course it is just an impression from the structure and joins overview, you're the one knowing :-)